# Sending UDP packets on iPhone fails over a fresh new 3G connection, but works otherwise

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, udp

I'm having a strange problem when sending UDP packets from an iPhone over a 3G. Almost every time my application starts after a longer period of network inactivity (for instance after the phone comes from the sleep mode or it just gets a 3G connection), my application is not able to send any UDP packets. I get a `kCFSocketError` error status from `CFSocketSendData`. The application logic then **re-tries to send the packet periodically** every five seconds, but no matter how long I let it run **it keeps failing**. However, when I switch the application to background and open, for instance, a web page in Safari (while the application is still failing on background), the application suddenly starts working. Basically, it seems like the other network activity (from Safari, Maps etc.) "kicks off the networking for real". Do I need to do anything special in terms of network initialisation for instance?

This is a simplified snippet of the code I'm using to send the UDP packets:

```
CFSocketRef cfSocket = CFSocketCreate(NULL, 0, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP, kCFSocketNoCallBack, NULL, NULL);
if (!cfSocket)
{
    // snip: some error handling
}

struct sockaddr_in addr;
// snip: init addr

CFDataRef cfAddr = CFDataCreate(NULL, (unsigned char *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

CFSocketError sendPacketResult = CFSocketSendData(cfSocket, cfAddr, cfPacketData, 0.0);
if (sendPacketResult != kCFSocketSuccess)
{
    // try again in 5 seconds
}
```

It all works fine without any problems over Wi-Fi.

To be fair, I think I've seen sometimes (but very occasionally) the same behaviour in the standard iPhone applications (Safari, Maps, ...) as well. Sometimes they refuse to connect (even thought I see the 3G icon) and I need to close and reopen them. But it's very rare.

**Edit:** Possibly related question: [On iPhone, what does EPERM (errno == 1) mean in reponse to send() of UDP data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511783).

Answer (score 4):

The 3G TCP/IP network interface can be torn down by IOS at the operating system's pleasure, generally for power-saving reasons if there is no traffic going across it. When using BSD sockets (for example, for UDP, since there is no UDP apple  networking framework) there's no published OS call for ensuring the 3G network interface is up. But internally in Apple's CFSocketStream class there exists private Apple calls that wake up the interface.

So the solution seems to be to open up a CFSocketStream to someplace. That will wake up the interface for some period of time. As long as you send data over the CFSocketStream once a minute or so the connection and the network interface will stay up.

This isn't all that attractive, since it's only working by side effect. But it seems to be the only solution at this point.